# Which search platform should I use for static HTML sites without any branding or ads?

Tags: html, search, static

I'm building a fairly big HTML website (over 12,000 pages and counting) and looking for a way to add search to it. I'm looking for a way to do it without any ads or branding (so that leaves Google out, that I'm aware of).

I'd like something that's fairly easy to do and fairly cheap, but would be willing to pay for quality, if needed. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can make search option using JavaScript. Easy example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)

To avoid google you can make it without SEO tags.